# mix razor view with handlebar templates

Tags: razor, handlebars.js

I'm using ASP MVC with Razor view engine to build web application.

I'm also using EmberJS on some views for client side rich application framework.
EmberJS uses handlebar templates.

The problem is that visual studio lose the ability to color-code the HTML elements inside the handlebar script tab like so:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div>
    <div>@ShowRes.NumberOfNodesInNetwork: {{App.nodesController.arrangedContent.length}}</div>
    <div>@ShowRes.NumberOfLinksInNetwork: {{App.linksController.arrangedContent.length}}</div>
</div>
</scrtip>
```

The div element inside the script tag is not color-coded.

Any idea how to cause VS2012 to ignore the script tag and simply treat the HTML elements as if no script element exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that without custom plugin for visual studio it is not possible to get syntax highlight inside handlebar template.